# Simple SPL-token stake vault

Tags: spl-token, stake

I'm looking for a simple vault-like for SPL-tokens, something like ERC-4626 for evm, you deposit tokens and you receive shares, then if the pool has more tokens your shares worth more.

Reading the solana guides, I need something like staking pools but without the validators part. I saw a few examples (like metaplex) but almost everything is NFT oriented.

Maybe in the SPL there's something like that? staking/lending with extra params? Governance without the DAO part?..

Thanks in advance =D

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a definite answer, but you could probably cobble together something based on SPL Single-Validator Stake Pool and SPL Token Swap. The hardest problem to solve with a vault with multiple token types is how to value them with respect to each other.

For example, for SPL Single-Validator Stake Pool, there's only lamports, so you can do a simple value of the pool tokens compared to the lamports managed by the pool.

For an AMM, however, you need a way to value the different token types (e.g. token A and B) with respect to each other, ie. say that the total value of the pool tokens is `sqrt(amount_of_token_A * amount_of_token_B)`.

In a lending protocol, however, you'll likely use an oracle to figure out the value of the lent tokens vs the borowed tokens.

Comment: The idea is to stake only one token. Something like the "governance" with the buyback + inject mechanism, but without the governance part. Thank you for your answer anyway :+1: